# Conditional Probability Problem (3 Cards, 1 red-red, 1 red-black, 1 black-black)

Tags: probability

Our class got into a heated debate over a question that even my professor couldn't answer with certainty. So here's the problem:

"Of three cards, one is painted red on both sides; one is painted black on both sides; and one is painted red on one side and black on the other. A card is randomly chosen and placed on a table. If the side facing up is red, what is the probability that the other side is also red?"

Our class is split into the "1/2" and the "2/3" camp. I lean more towards 1/2. My argument is that when you uncover the red card, the black-black card is no longer considered in the sample space. So there are only 2 cards remaining, and since only one of those cards will have red on its other side, the final probability is 1/2.

My professor leans more towards 2/3. He didn't have time to formulate his argument fully, however. I've been trying to think about an alternative explanation which would lead to 2/3 as an answer, but it always leads back to the same argument I used for 1/2. Which one would be correct, and why?

Comment: The answer is $2/3.$ Bayes' Rule easily shows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that, beforehand, you took the card that is red on both sides, and used invisible ink to number the sides $1$ and $2$.

---

The card that is on the table is showing a red face.

This red face can be one of three faces, each equally likely:

- it could be the side with an invisible $1$ on it
- it could be the side with an invisible $2$ on it
- it could be the side with no invisible ink on it (the red side of the card with one side of each color)

---

Of these three equally likely possibilities, two of them imply that the facedown side of the card is red, so we get $$\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have randomly selected one of the three red sides to be showing.  Two of the three of them have a red side on the bottom, so the chance is $\frac 23$.  Yes, the black-black card is out of the picture, but the red-red card is twice as likely to be the card because you also eliminate half the times you choose the red-black card-the times the black face is up.

Answer (score 1):

> My argument is that when you uncover the red card, the black-black card is no longer considered in the sample space.

It eliminates more than that.

The card is selected (1 from 3), and a side from that card is shown (1 from 2), without bias.   So this experiment may be represented using a sample space consisting of six unbiased outcomes.   Of these, witnessing a red side eliminates *not just* the two outcomes for the double black card, but *also* the outcome of "the two-colour card shows black".

$$\{R_1(R_2), R_2(R_1), R_3(B_3),\require{cancel} \cancel{B_3(R_3), B_2(B_1), B_1(B_2)}\}$$

So there are three red sides you could be looking at with equal probability.  Two of them have another red side on the flipside.   Thus giving the answer.

$$\dfrac 23$$